# SUSY and proton decay

Tags: supersymmetry, proton-decay

If proton decays are NOT observed and we manage to push the lower bound to its lifetime at about 10³⁶ or 10³⁷ years...Can we prove SUSY is wrong or can we always build SUSY models for any proton lifetime?

Comment: Generically one would expect SUSY effects to be suppressed by a factor inversely proportional to some power of the SUSY scale, i.e. non-observation simply puts bounds on the SUSY scale. Why do you single out proton decay here, and do you have any specific reason to expect a non-decaying proton to *rule out* SUSY rather than putting bounds on the SUSY scale?

Comment: The question you should be asking is more subtle than that. In most cases a beyond-the-standard-model theory is attractive because it solves several problems at once, and constraints on the theory could make it unappealing not because it prove that the theory can't be so but because it turns some knob until one or more of those explanations is not longer sufficient. This is the situation that will come up if the current direct WIMP search experiments come up dry: they might or might not actually be WIMPs, but they won't solve the dark matter question any more.

Comment: Do you really mean "probe", or was that a typo for "prove"?

Answer (score 1):

Models can always be probed. It seems from the literature that $6$D SUSY SO$(10)$ is a solid candidate.

As a result of Bose statistics for superfields, the total anti-symmetry in the colour index requires that the operators leading to proton decay are flavor non-diagonal. For further reading, see [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370269382903136?via%3Dihub) for details on how, in the presence of a discrete symmetry which occurs in an $SU(5)$ supersymmetric unified model the authors obtain a definite prediction for the dominant decay mode, i.e. $p \mapsto K^{\pm}ν_μ$ and $n \mapsto K^{0−}ν_μ$ (latter for Neutrons obviously).

Comment: The second ($n\rightarrow K^- \nu_\mu$) seems for me not preserving charge?